# The required layout_width and layout_height attributes are missing

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got the following layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<item android:id="@+id/descriptions_menu"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
      android:title="Toggle Descriptions On/ Off" />

<item android:id="@+id/settings_menu"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
      android:title="Settings" />
```

But I keep getting this error:
    The required layout_width and layout_height attributes are missing

This is reported on lines 2, 9, 10. It seems totally bizarre. It's in an old project (>5 years) that I'm trying to resurrect.

Comment: is this your layout file or menu file ??

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. it's in res/layout/mainmenu.xml and it defines what used to be the menu (from pressing the menu button on the phone)

Comment: can you show us where your menu is added?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i think `menu` layout is not valid in `res/layout`, you need to place it in `res/menu` as stated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

> To define the menu, create an XML file inside your project's **res/menu/** directory and build the menu with the following elements

and you can inflate it using [MenuInflater.inflate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.Menu))

Answer (score 3):

If this is the menu file then you have to close the menu tag at the end of file,
Make sure this file is in res > menu folder > menu file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <item android:id="@+id/descriptions_menu"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
          android:title="Toggle Descriptions On/ Off" />

    <item android:id="@+id/settings_menu"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
          android:title="Settings" />
    </menu>
```

Comment: well spotted, I am actually doing that but I missed it in the copy/ paste